# Adding line in case value is in list

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to automatically copy and insert a line in an Excel sheet if the user selects a specific value from a drop down list?

Suppose the drop down list is column 2 (product) and takes values "Apple" & "Pear". Each time a user selects Apple, the lines should be duplicated. For instance

| Name | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Apple | 1 |
| B | Pear | 1 |
| C | Apple | 1 |

If the user selects Apple, the end result should be

| Name | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Apple | 1 |
| A | Apple | 1 |
| B | Pear | 1 |
| C | Apple | 1 |
| C | Apple | 1 |

If so, could anyone tell me how to do it ?

I have written this code so far but no new lines are being created

```
Sub Addline()    
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LR as Integer

    LR = Sheets("Customer").Range("A7").EndXlDown.Row
    For i = 7 to LR
        Set Rng = Sheets("Customer").Range("E" & i)
        If Rng = "Apple" Then
           Rng.Offset(Rowoffset).EntireRow.Insert Shift:= xlShiftDown
        End If
    Next
End sub
```

Then in worksheet_change()

```
Call Addline
```

If i modify line in the sheet, it ends up adding several lines instead of only one.

Comment: It should be possible so what have you tried? Edit your question, include your code and explain what's not working with your code

Comment: You'll need to use a `Worksheet_Change()` event, that code won't call itself.

Comment: @dwirony I've tried to use the worksheet_Change to call the code but it's giving me an error message on Addline Target.Value

Comment: What is `Rowoffset`? Where is it defined?